# WP Admin: Include custom post type archive in link search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for examples of this online and through the WP documentation on filters but I can't find a suitable hook, so apologies for posting a question without a good example of what I'm trying to do!

When you add a link to text or to a button in the editor, you can search for the page/post you want to link to. What you can't search for is a post type archive link.

I want to be able to type the name of a post type into the search box (pictured below), and include the post type archive link in the search results. In this example, I have a post type called `members` that I'd like to link to.

[image]

I find the need to do this a lot, and I always end up just typing `/post-type-link` into the box and leaving it at that, but I don't think this is an elegant solution and is clunky for users.

I have tried to write some code, but I don't believe I have the right hook:

```
function include_cpt_search( $query ) {

    if ( is_admin() && is_single() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'services' ) );
    }

    return $query;

}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_cpt_search' );
```

Has anyone done this before? Know of a filter or hook I could work with? Anything really!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Link format in the RichText toolbar uses the Search REST API endpoint at [`/wp/v2/search`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/search-results/#list-search-results), so although that endpoint doesn't provide a specialized hook for filtering the *response*, you can use [`rest_post_dispatch`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_dispatch/) to add custom links to the search results returned via `/wp/v2/search`.

So in the examples below, I'm checking if the route is `/wp/v2/search` and if so, then we add the (custom) post type's archive link. Also note that, you should provide an array with the items mentioned [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control#search-suggestion-values) (the `LinkControl` component used by the Link format).

### Basic Example

Includes only the (i.e. one) post type whereby its name matched exactly the search keyword.

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_dispatch', 'so_62472641', 10, 3 );
function so_62472641( $response, $server, $request ) {
    // Don't modify the data if the REST API route is not /wp/v2/search
    if ( 'post' !== $request->get_param( 'type' ) ||
        '/wp/v2/search' !== $request->get_route() ) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Let's see if there's a post type that matched the search keyword.
    $search = $request->get_param( 'search' );
    if ( ! $post_type = get_post_type_object( $search ) ) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Now add the post type archive URL, if any, to the response data.
    if ( $url = get_post_type_archive_link( $search ) ) {
        $data = (array) $response->get_data();

        $data[] = [
            'id'    => 'post_type-' . $search,
            'type'  => 'Post Type Archive',
            'title' => $post_type->label,
            'url'   => $url,
        ];

        $response->set_data( $data );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

### Extended Example

Includes all post types whereby the name/label matched the search keyword.

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_dispatch', 'so_62472641', 10, 3 );
function so_62472641( $response, $server, $request ) {
    // Don't modify the data if the REST API route is not /wp/v2/search
    if ( 'post' !== $request->get_param( 'type' ) ||
        '/wp/v2/search' !== $request->get_route() ) {
        return $response;
    }

    $search = $request->get_param( 'search' );
    $post_types = get_post_types( [], 'objects' );
    $extra_data = [];

    // Let's see if there's a post type that matched the search keyword.
    foreach ( $post_types as $obj ) {
        if ( $search === $obj->name ||
            // look for the search keyword in the post type name/slug and labels (plural & singular)
            false !== stripos( "{$obj->name} {$obj->label} {$obj->labels->singular_name}", $search )
        ) {
            if ( $url = get_post_type_archive_link( $obj->name ) ) {
                $extra_data[] = [
                    'id'    => 'post_type-' . $obj->name,
                    'type'  => 'Post Type Archive',
                    'title' => $obj->label,
                    'url'   => $url,
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    // Now add the post type archive links, if any, to the response data.
    if ( ! empty( $extra_data ) ) {
        $response->set_data( array_merge( (array) $response->get_data(), $extra_data ) );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

### Sample Output (for the second example above)

[image: Sample output for the second example]

Note: The above is a screenshot of a real response, but I deliberately (via PHP) changed the domain name to `example.com` (i.e. the actual domain name is different).

And the examples were both tried & tested working on WordPress 5.5.1 (latest release as of writing). Also, you can exclude the default `post` post type, if you want to.

### Additional Notes

1. It should be noted that the examples do not take into account the pagination, which means, if there were 10 post types that matched the search keyword, then they would always be included in the response (on page 1, 2, 3, etc.). So you might want to just use the first example because at least it always includes at most 1 post type only. However, with the second example, you can actually limit the `$extra_data` to, say, 5 items (per page - but it's up to you on how to distribute the items per page).
2. You can also use a custom search handler class, e.g. one that extends the default class ([`WP_REST_Post_Search_Handler`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_post_search_handler/)) and use the [`wp_rest_search_handlers` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_rest_search_handlers/) to add your class to the list. Here's a very basic example...

   In `your-class.php`:

   ```php
   class My_WP_REST_Post_Search_Handler extends WP_REST_Post_Search_Handler {
       // ... you'll need to actually write the code on your own..
   }

   return new My_WP_REST_Post_Search_Handler;
   ```

   In the theme's `functions.php` file or somewhere in your plugin:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'wp_rest_search_handlers', 'my_wp_rest_search_handlers' );
   function my_wp_rest_search_handlers( $search_handlers ) {
       $search_handlers[] = include_once '/path/to/the/your-class.php';

       return $search_handlers;
   }
   ```

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you. I'll test this tomorrow/friday and accept as the answer if it works as expected.